# Prove the identity (complex numbers trigonometric form)

Tags: complex-numbers

Please shed some light on how I can start the proof.

$$\sin{\alpha} +r\sin({\alpha + \phi}) + ... + r^n\sin({\alpha} + n\phi) \\= {\frac{\sin{\alpha}-r\sin({\alpha} - {\phi}) - r^{n+1}\sin((n+1){\phi} + {\alpha}) + r^{n+2}\cos(n{\phi} + {\alpha})}{1-2r\cos{\phi} + r^2}}.$$

Comment: You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `proof-verification`? That is, which proof do you want us to verify?

Comment: Observe that, for each new term, the angle is rotated by a constant angle $\phi$ and the magnitude is multiplied by a constant factor $r$. Therefore the whole thing can be viewed as the imaginary part of the geometric series $\sum_{k = 0}^n z_k$ where

\begin{align}
z_k &= z_0 \cdot a^k & z_0 &= \cos\alpha + i \sin\alpha & a = r\cdot(\cos\phi + i \sin\phi)
\end{align}

Can you take it from here? Honestly this question post should be closed since you're not showing any effort.